# Performing lookups with merged cells in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs, gs-vlookup

Given a set of multi-dimensional data represented in a Google Spreadsheet:

```
 A | 1 | x
 A | 2 | y
 A | 3 | z
```

It is pretty straightforward to do a lookup on multiple values using the `FILTER` and `INDEX` functions.  Doing a lookup for `A2` would result in `y`.  However, if the similar data is merged into a single cell:

```
   | 1 | x
 A | 2 | y
   | 3 | z
```

Is there a function that would accomplish the same thing?  the `FILTER` method only returns the first row in the implicit set because there is only an `A` actually on the first row.

If interested, [you can view the live sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15EKxJwafEHdCPvO4zj9dw0ii2rXKxF-chtTmUR0lX5s/edit?usp=sharing) using the 'Rules' sheet.

I have been working on a custom function, but am hoping for something more portable.  Helper cells would be fine, as long as I can hide them on a separate sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, using the helper cells idea, would be to "normalise" your Rules sheet on a separate (hidden) sheet, and perform lookups on that sheet. Eg, in A3 of that sheet:

`=ArrayFormula(HLOOKUP(IF(ROW(Rules!A3:A),Rules!A2),Rules!A2:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(Rules!A3:A),FILTER(ROW(Rules!A3:A),LEN(Rules!A3:A)),1)-1,0))`

and fill that formula across to the right as far as required. Note: this formula will only work on the new version of Sheets (which you are using).

Comment: it would be nice to have this explained.